# PHP Simple HTML DOM object decoding

Tags: php, ajax, parsing, dom

I try to do this:

```
$html = file_get_html ( 'http://www.ebay.com/cln/explorer/_ajax?page=1&ipp=16&catids=37958' );
foreach ( $html->find ( 'div[class="connection"]' ) as $collection ) {
    echo "found collections: ".count($collection);
```

Problem is, the returned file from the AJAX request contains elements encoded like:

```
<div class=\"collection\" data-collectionid=\"75336256016\">
<div class=\"header\">
```

Can anyone please help me to transform all the `\"` in the DOM object back to the normal `"`.
Or change the `->find` command to find the right element.

Thanks so much!

Comment: That page give you JSON plus an html comment on the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response of the ebay is JSON, but there is a `<!-- RlogId t6%60jjpfg%3C%3D%60mb6a54d.47e3-143fd4a3ae7-0x32337a -->` or something like this at the end of the response.

First you need to clean up that string..

Than json_decode .. value of the html key is your html that you need to parse..

Once you cleaned up and json_decode the response the real html you looked for will be on the object named html.. take a look the code below.. I am pretty sure you can use better var names...

```
include('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html ( 'http://www.ebay.com/cln/explorer/_ajax?page=1&ipp=16&catids=37958' );
$str = $html->save();


$strparts = explode('<!-- RlogId',$str);
$json = $strparts[0];


$htmlcleanedup = json_decode($json);

$domhtml = str_get_html($htmlcleanedup->html);

$ret = $domhtml->find('div[class=collection]'); 

echo count($ret);
?>
```

Comment: of course.. but if Ebay put that stupid random code below this response it means they don't want ppl to use it..

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = file_get_html ( 'http://www.ebay.com/cln/explorer/_ajax?page=1&ipp=16&catids=37958' );
$html = stripslashes($html);

var_dump($html);

string '<div class="collection" data-collectionid="75336256016">
<div class="header">' (length=78)
```

Comment: Work like charm for eliminating the \'s.
However, $html is no object anymore. Cant use $html->find on it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I don't know what you're doing in the `file_get_html` function. You should use `stripslashes` right after you get the content of the url and then convert it to a DOM object.

Comment: I was following the manual at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm.
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
Sorry to bother you but can you help me with the steps you just described please?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `stripslashes()` function:

http://php.net/stripslashes